# Google Analytics Experiments: неравномерное распределение сессий

Tags: google-analytics

Создал эксперимент в Google Analytics в котором задал всего один вариант и эксперимент на 100% трафика.

Потом добавил в Google Tag Manager следующий тэг:

```
#script with api
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=1EN3yB34T0WE-0WxSqvsKw"></script>
<script>
    # item ids to launch test
    var itemIds= ['898324', '914734', '904249', '936082', '904275', '951077', '977818', '942227', '933907'];
    if( $.inArray({{productId}}, itemIds) !== -1 ) {
        # get chosed variation
        var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();
        $(function(){   
            if (chosenVariation == 1) {
                $('div.orange.service').hide();
                $('div.orange.cardif').hide();
            }
        });

        # make non-interaction hit to send data. Maybe here i get mistake 
        #(hit making by send data to Google Tag Manager, and all events with event === OWOX - will send to Google Analytics)
        dataLayer.push({"event":"OWOX","eventCategory":"Non-Interactions","eventAction":"show","eventLabel":"products","products":[]});
    }
</script>
```

После 7 дней выполнения теста я получил [следующие результаты](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSMKh.png) (абсолютно неравномерное распределение сессий между оригинальным вариантом и измененным)

Из-за чего такое может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> После 7 дней выполнения теста я получил следующие результаты
>   (абсолютно неравномерное распределение сессий между оригинальным
>   вариантом и измененным)
>
> Из-за чего такое может быть?

В начале эксперимента Google Analytics действительно распределяет трафик равномерно, но после того, как получены первые результаты Google направляет больше трафика на тот вариант, который лучше. Вот, как об этом сказано в [справке](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2844870):

> Мы замеряем результаты вашего эксперимента дважды в день и определяем,
>   какие варианты оказались более эффективными. Затем мы соответствующим
>   образом корректируем долю трафика, которую каждый из вариантов будет
>   получать в дальнейшем. Лучший вариант получает больше трафика, худший–
>   меньше.

Если вы хотите, чтобы трафик распределялся равномерно на протяжении всего периода эксперимента, то в настройках нужно включить Distribute traffic evenly across all variations:

[image: Distribute traffic evenly across all variations "ON"]

Comment: Спасибо большое, сам это прочитал только сегодня с утра. Так называемый "многорукий бандит"